# how to change value of last item in collection?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

lets say you have this simple collection:

```
 $c = collect([
     ['active'=>false],
     ['active'=>false],
     ['active'=>false],
    ]
 );
```

I want to change the last item to set active to true
is there any easy collectionish way rather than something like:

```
$collection->toArray();
$collection[count($collection)-1]['active'] = true;
$newCollection = collect($collection);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all laravel collections are array accessible and you don't need to call `toArray`.
As for you issue you can do this:

`$last = $collection->pop();
 $last['active'] = true
 $collection->push($last)`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-pop
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-push

Comment: thanks so simple, like I know about pop() and push() but not connected it in my mind :)

Comment: There is less operations by using *last()* method: `$collection->last()['active'] = true;`

Comment: Using `last()` you can retrieve value but not modify https://github.com/illuminate/support/blob/c371bff488ce3ec3270091d77cf2e825cfeb74f3/Arr.php#L157